# How can I make IF without ELSE on SQL WHERE condition?

Tags: sql

I`m trying to make a querie that selects users and if user type equals 1 I need to select those with age. My table:

```
  id (int 11) | type (int 11) | email (varchar 25) | age (int 11)
```

My querie:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE IF(type = 1, age <> 0)`

The problem is that I need to have an ELSE condition, but I dont need one in this case. How can I make an IF inside WHERE without else condition?

Thanks

Comment: the specification is a bit unclear, example data and sample output would go a long ways to explaining the requirement.  which rows should be returned?  we can suggest a variety of SQL constructs that return a variety of results.  "if user type equals 1 ... those with age" ... what about rows where type is not 1, or is null, ...  Why are we storing age? Shouldn't we be calculating age as a difference from todays date and a date in the past, like date of birth, registration date,

Comment: The main problem is to create IF without ELSE condition. If I could do that I would solve my problem

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (there is no `IF` in standard SQL). Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Comment: @TiagoCastro:  i think we are trying to solve the wrong "main problem" here. (The big rock problems here seem to be the lack of a clear specification; there are a variety of interpretations of which rows should be returned, and which are to be excluded. Another big rock problem seems to be the requirement to include an `IF` function in the `WHERE` clause. We can do that. But it's very likely we can return an equivalent result without the `IF` function, possibly with SQL constructs that can make effective use of an index.

Comment: @TiagoCastro:  I think the "main problem" you've identified is (possibly) of the XY variety,   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem  forpas and Gordon have suggested SQL constructs that will return a resultset. Neither uses the MySQL IF() function in the WHERE clause. Both answers seem to ignore the reported "main problem" of having an IF without an ELSE;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** How do I make IF without ELSE on SQL WHERE condition ?

**A:** It's not possible; there is always an ELSE. MySQL IF() function has three arguments. It doesn't matter where the IF() function is used, whether it's part of an expression in a WHERE clause, or an expression in the SELECT list.

As an alternative to the MySQL `IF()` function, we can use a more portable, more  ANSI-standard compliant `CASE` expression. But that doesn't get away from the crux of the question, about avoiding an ELSE.  There is always an ELSE with the CASE expression as well. If we omit the ELSE clause, it's the same as if we had specified `ELSE NULL`.

---

---

As an aside (unrelated to the question that was asked), I don't think we should be storing `age` as an attribute; typically age is the difference between the current date and a date in the past (date of birth, registration date, etc.)

---

I'm thinking we don't need an `IF` function in the `WHERE` clause. (That's specific to MySQL, so this answer assumes that the target DBMS is MySQL, and not some other RDBMS).

We can use a combination of conditions, combined with `NOT`, `AND`, `OR` and parens so specify an order of operations.

Sample data and example output goes a long way to explaining the spec.

```
 id  type  age    email
 --  ----  ----   ----------
  1     0     0   1@one
  2     1     0   2@two
  3     0     1   3@three
  4     1     1   4@four
  5     0  NULL   5@five
  6     1  NULL   6@six
  7  NULL  NULL   7@seven
  8  NULL     0   8@eight
  9  NULL     1   9@nine
```

Which of these rows should be returned, and which rows should be excluded?

Here is an example query (MySQL specific syntax) that returns all rows except row id=2  (type=1, age=0)

```
 SELECT u.id
      , u.type
      , u.age
      , u.email
   FROM user u
  WHERE NOT ( u.type <=> 1 ) 
     OR NOT ( u.age  <=> 0 )
```

If there's a requirement to incorporate `IF` functions, we can do that, and return an equivalent result:

```
 SELECT u.id
      , u.type
      , u.age
      , u.email
   FROM user u
  WHERE NOT ( IF( u.type <=> 1 ,1,0) )
     OR NOT ( IF( u.age  <=> 0 ,1,0) )
              ^^^              ^^^^^
```

---

In the `WHERE` clause, an expression will be evaluated as a boolean value.  A numeric value of 0 is FALSE, a non-zero value is TRUE, and NULL value is (as always) just NULL.

For a row to be returned, we need the expression in the `WHERE` clause to evaluate to a non-zero value (to evaluate to TRUE).

The third argument of the `IF()` function is the "else" value; for that value, we can return TRUE, FALSE or NULL. To exclude rows that do not satisfy the `type=1` condition, we return either zero or NULL:

```
  WHERE IF(type = 1, age <> 0 ,0 )
                              ^^
```

or equivalently:

```
  WHERE IF(type = 1, age <> 0 ,NULL )
                              ^^^^^
```

If we want rows that don't satisfy `type=1` condition to be returned, we can return any non-zero value:

```
  WHERE IF(type = 1, age <> 0 ,42 )
                              ^^^
```

---

RECAP:

Addressing the question that was asked:

Q: How do I make IF without ELSE on SQL WHERE condition ?

A: There is always an ELSE value with the MySQL IF() function; in the context of the WHERE clause, the value will be evaluated as a boolean: TRUE, FALSE or NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `CASE`:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE age = CASE WHEN type <> 1 THEN age ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: The query pattern here returns a result compatible with one possible interpretation of the spec. But OP reports in a comment "The main problem is to create IF without ELSE condition"

Comment: @spencer7593 IF() is a function in MySql that needs 3 arguments. It's not possible to use it with only 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE type <> 1 OR age <> 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

I was in a similar situation and ended up with the following solution:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE IF(type = 1, age <> 0, 1=0)`

The else part here is `1 = 0` which is never true, so you don't select anything in that case.